# How to change urls generated by admin generator. Also how to return 404 for backend.php

Tags: php, symfony1

I am using Symfony 1.2.9 (with Propel ORM), to build a website. I have only started using the admin generator.

I have got the admin generator to work so far (thanks to the folks here at SO). The one remaining thing is that I want to change the urls generated by the admin generator. I dont like the fact that it lists the module names plainly in the browser, I would like to give them my own names (I suppose security by obfuscation is slightly better than nothing).

Secondly, I dont like the fact that anyone can type backend.php and be greeted with a login screen (I have secure the entire app). I have checked with some of the well known sites using Symfony and all of them return a page not found when I type in 'backend.php' or (shock/horror) 'backend_dev.php'.

Can anyone please recommend how I can forward404 when someone directly types http://mywebsite/backend.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For backend.php see "Remove "/backend.php/" from your uri" on [Symfony Check](http://symfony-check.org/#todo11).

For the module names: you can specify in the `route.yml`how the URLs should look like, e.g.

```
routeNameForAdminModule:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                yourModel
    module:               yourModule
    prefix_path:          path/prefix    <- this option
```

Ok this is for Doctrine, I don't know if it is the same for Propel but you can give it a try ;)

Comment: Felix: You're SIMPLY THE BEST!

Comment: I just like symfony and encountered similar problems myself ;) But thank you :)